# logd shortcut doesn't work in Intellij with Kotlin

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

Logging Java in Intellij is easy with shortcuts such as 'logt', 'logd', 'loge'... and so on. But I moved to Kotlin, I noticed that those shortcuts doesn't work anymore. I don't know if it has something to do with my configuration, but if not, how can I fix this?

Comment: Just created the templates as described by [Leo Droidcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46154955/4540114) (@Leo Droidcoder Thanks!) and uploaded them to [Github](https://github.com/TobiasUhmann/android-studio-log-templates-for-kotlin). Simply download the .jar and import it in Android Studio via 'File > Import Settings...'

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should create separate templates to make them work correctly.
Here is the step-by-step guide:

Firstly, Copy and paste AndroidLog templates to Kotlin (Just select them and use CMD+C, CMD+V (or Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V)
Secondly, You have to adjust them manually:
 1. **logd** (and others) 
Select the **logd** item and press "Edit variables"
[image]

Change expression to: `kotlinFunctionName()`
[image]

Also, remove `;` from the end of the template, as you don't need it in Kotlin.

Now your method name will be shown correctly

2. **logt**
   This one is a bit trickier.
   **Solution 1 TAG = class name.**

   - Template text :

   **private val TAG = "$className$"**

   - Edit variables -> Expression:

   **groovyScript("_1.take(Math.min(23, _1.length()));", kotlinClassName())**

**Solution 2 TAG = file name** (can be used inside Companion)

- Template text :

  **private const val TAG = "$className$**

or:

```
companion object {
     private const val TAG = "$className$"
}
```

- Edit variables -> Expression:

  **groovyScript("_1.take(Math.min(23, _1.length()));", fileNameWithoutExtension())**

---

### **Edit 19.02.19**

Also, it might be useful for someone.
In order to avoid creating the `TAG` variable, you can use the class name as a variable, for instance:

```
Log.d("BaseActivity", "onCreate: ")
```

Where `BaseActivity` is the class name.

The template will look now as:

```
android.util.Log.d("$CLASS_NAME$", "$METHOD_NAME$: $content$")
```

Where `CLASS_NAME` variable is:

```
groovyScript("_1.take(Math.min(23, _1.length()));", fileNameWithoutExtension())
```

Comment: I've tried this method but it doesn't seem to take effect after I "Apply"

Comment: @Chace make sure you make changes to the right language (Java/Kotlin)

Comment: @Chace I had the same problem, the error was that the context wasn't defined, I selected Kotlin, If you have the same problem you will see a warning symbol in the same configuration template with the message "No applicable context"

Comment: Copy and paste AndroidLog templates - BUT from where do I copy and paste ?

Comment: @KaranSharma 1. open Android studio Preferences/Settings 2. Type "logd" in search. -> it will find you the templates in Editor->Live Templates-> AndroidLog. Where AndroidLog is a category, where you see templates such as logd, loge etc. 3. Now you select the ones you want to copy (for instance logd and loge), press Ctrl+C (or Cmd+C on Mac). 4. Now instead of AndroidLog select the Kotlin category and paste there

Comment: It didn't work for me! @LeoDroidcoder. In android 4 there is AndroidLogKotlin block and all of them are selected but still doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

These are provided in IntelliJ as a Live Template configuration for `AndroidLog` (found in `Preferences -> Editor -> Live Templates`), and are applicable specifically to Java code: [image: AndroidLog Live Template config]

There isn't anything broken in your configuration, but if you want to make these Live Templates available for Kotlin you will need to add new Live Template for `AndroidLog` and make them applicable to Kotlin code.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html

There's an open feature request to have them added as defaults here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10464

Answer (score 0):

Change the scope of the template in the applicable option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 4.0 there's new **AndroidLogKotlin** block. You can implement @LeoDroidcoder's solution there.