# Auto implement method Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

When I implement methods from interface by hitting Alt + Enter, the implement method should be at the bottom of class. But in Kotlin, it stays on the top (as you can see the method showToast). It is inconvinient because it is above onCreate and I also want to remove the //TODO comment when I implement methods automatically!

And normally, when I write logi in Java, Android studio automatically generates Log.i(TAG, ..) but it seems not to work in Kotlin

Can anyone show me how to do that. Thanks

[image]

Comment: For the position of the implemented method: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350594/kotlin-how-can-i-let-android-studio-implement-interfaces-function-at-bottom-of); For logi template: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44556828/logd-shortcut-doesnt-work-in-intellij-with-kotlin); For auto-generated TODO statement: You may follow the instruction of the comment and find the setting of "New Kotlin Function Body".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To avoid Todo comment follow below mentioned steps

1. Go to `File -> Setting` (That will  bring new window in front)
2. Go to `Editor -> Code Style -> File and Code Template`
3. Select the `Code` tab from the right panel
4. Scroll down the list of options and find out 'New Kotlin Function Body' option
5. Remove the default text and done

You will not get any todo comment line in overriding method now. hope that helps you

Comment: It still creates the function on top.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is still open at JetBrains tracker. Vote and track progress over [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12291)